# Calling Power BI REST API from an unattended process

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I'd like to start using the Power BI REST API to update data.

Is it possible to get an authentication token without prompting a user for their credentials ?  My application is a Windows Service that runs on a server.

The examples I've seen so far seem to require a user to supply their AAD credentials in order to get a token.

Is it possible to call the API from an unattended process?  If so, any examples you guys know about.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make this work. I don't have a code example handy, but I know this is possible.  There are two paths for it. Path one is store the username + pwd and supply it in the authentication credential.  The better (security at cost of complexity) path is to ask a user to enter their credentials and then store a refresh token and use that to get an access token when needed. Refresh token expire after 90 days so you need to periodically have a user login again.  For path one, you need to figure out how to securely store the username and password and deal with password change.